# php websocket connection establishment error

Tags: php, symfony, sockets, firewall

I have installed Symfony 3 on Ubuntu LAMP stack (PHP 7). I need websockets on my website so I:

1. Added `gos/web-socket-bundle` to my symfony via composer
2. Set config:

`gos_web_socket:
    server:
        port: 4000
        host: mydomain.com`

3. Opened port via firewall `sudo ufw allow 4000/tcp` and `sudo ufw allow 4000`.
4. Then I started server `php bin/console gos:websocket:server` and it's running.

But when I try to connect from js:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://mydomain.com:4000');
```

It gives the error:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://mydomain.com:4000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: If you change host to 0.0.0.0 does it work?  Check `netstat -anop|grep LISTEN` to ensure it is listening on the right port address and interface.

Comment: Are you testing it on localhost or any other hosting provider.

Comment: changing host to 0.0.0.0 solved the problem ;) @drew010

Comment: I'm testing on vps ubuntu + LEMP (PHP 7) @AgamBanga

Comment: There might  be port issue. You need to check if the port is open or not.You can check it by `telnet mydomain.com 4000`. If you don't get any response, then its not open. I have had this issue in AWS itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment provided by @drew010 resolved this for me.

In `config.yml` set `gos_web_socket.server.host` to `0.0.0.0`.